# Use protobuf-3.9.0 for c++ and happend error "use of typeid requires -frtti"

Tags: c++, macos, protocol-buffers

> I generate .pb.h and .ph.cc file of proto file with command "protoc --proto_path=. --cpp_out=. stat.proto"
> This is my proto file

```
message LogStream {
  string uid = 1;           
   string device_id = 2;     
   string device_model = 3;  
   uint32 os = 4;  
   string os_version = 5;      
   string client_version = 6; 
   string client_ip = 7;      
   uint32 network =8;  
   string country = 9;       
   string sdk_version = 10;  
   uint32 biz = 11;         
   string app_id = 12;      
   string data_source = 13; 
  repeated string log = 14;     
}
```

Then i compile my program using clang++ with any no flag about protobuf and occurs error in "AllocHook(RTTI_TYPE_ID(T), n);" , error as below

```
template <typename T>   
PROTOBUF_ALWAYS_INLINE void* AllocateInternal(bool skip_explicit_ownership) {
        const size_t n = internal::AlignUpTo8(sizeof(T));
        AllocHook(RTTI_TYPE_ID(T), n);
        // Monitor allocation if needed.
        if (skip_explicit_ownership) {
          return impl_.AllocateAligned(n);
        } else {
          return impl_.AllocateAlignedAndAddCleanup(
              n, &internal::arena_destruct_object<T>);
        }   }
```

Comment: Do you have rtti disabled?

Comment: no, i do nothing about protobuf when i compile it, i just link lib in cmakelist, like this: 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})

Comment: but do you disable RTTI somewhere else in your cmake file? Please show a [mre]